# Setting session timeout without web.xml in java web application

Tags: java, web.xml, session-timeout

Is it possible to set session timeout without setting in web.xml or servlet for java web application?
`<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60(time in minutes)</session-timeout>
</session-config>`
And how to read .txt file which contains time and give its value to set session-timeoout in web.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In web.xml:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Programmatically:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60)
```

And as for reading in the value of a text file, you could use a properties file (named anything you want) and load it from there using the built-in Java Properties classes.

Note, the numbers above are in minutes.

Comment: timeout value is in minutes not in seconds

Answer (score 1):

I believe, i agree with answer given by chris g. However, i have few things to highlight for you.

1. The effect of session time out in web.xml is global and applicable to all the sessions. But, setMaxInactiveInterval is a non static method and has effect of a particular session.
2. Setting 0 or less in session timeout tag in web.xml does not give any session timeout. But, setting 0 in setMaxInactiveInterval will immediate start closing the session.

Apart from this, setMaxInactiveInterval has same effect as session timeout tag except you can programmatically set session time out.

Thanks